# VSCode で Python ファイルの記述時にモジュールやメソッドに色が付かない

Tags: python, vscode

VSCodeでPythonのコードを書いております。今まではモジュールやメソッドに色がついていたのですが、新調したPCでは白のままになってしまいます。

PCは2台(Windows 10, Linux Mint)使用しており、特別設定をいじった覚えはないのですが2台とも色がついていたのに新調したPC(Windows 10)のVSCodeのみ色がつきません。設定の同期はしておりません。再インストールも行いましたが解決しませんでした。

元のPCの拡張機能をすべて無効化して1つずつ有効にしたところ、Python(ms-python.python)とPylanceを有効にした時点で色がつくところまでわかったのですが、この2つの拡張機能の設定を見比べても違いが判らず困っております。対応についてご教授願います。

**元のPCのVSCode**
[image: 元のPCのVSCode]

**新調したPCのVSCode**
[image: 新調したPCのVSCode]

Comment: メニューから\[表示]\[出力](Ctrl-K Ctrl-H) で右側から Python Language Server選んだとき何かメッセージ出てないでしょうか？(何らかの問題) あとほかに, test.py というテストパッケージと同じ名称使ってるけど止めたほうが(問題出るかもなので)

Comment: これかも？ https://qiita.com/NatsuToku/items/db7b27d0b0583167e4e8

Answer (score 1):

ここに書くのはまずいのでしょうが、ゲストログインでしたが再ログインとアカウントの復元ができなくなってしまったのでこちらに書かせていただきます。
解決いたしました。magicPyが干渉していたようでアンインストール時にディレクトリが削除されていないのが原因だったようです。フォルダの読み込み前に拡張機能のアンインストールをしていたので関係ないと思い記載しませんでした、申し訳ありません。

> oriri様　質問外のことにまで助言いただきありがとうございます。素直に助かります。
> kirara0048様　リンクまでありがとうございます。今後の参考にさせていただきます。